# Web browser displays the RAR files instead of downloading them

Tags: browser, download, rar, viewer

Firefox displays the RAR files (it actually shows the binary data on screen) instead of downloading them. How do I stop this? Is this a browser problem or server problem? Chrome works. So it seems to be a browser problem.

[Example](http://www.soft.tahionic.com/download-stormy%20web%20site%20builder/Download.html) of RAR file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The site returns the wrong content type for the .rar file namly `text` instead of `application/x-rar-compressed`. So it is a server problem.

Chrome deliberately ignores the sent MIME type from the server in this case. Stating:

```
Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type application/x-rar-compressed: "http://www.soft.tahionic.com/download-stormy%20web%20site%20builder/resources/Joongle_Setup.rar".
```

Solution in on the user side: Right click the download link and choose *'save target as'*.

To fix this on the server side add the following type definition either to the .htaccess or the apache.conf, assuming the server runs Apache.

```
AddType application/x-rar-compressed .rar
```

Comment: Do you know the 'permanent' solution? (The one for server)

Comment: @Silvester yes, answer is updated.

Comment: IT WORKED. THANKS!  -------    AddType application/x-rar-compressed .rar